# SQL query performance - single record, filtered by non-indexed column, sorted by indexed column, record is close in the sequence of sorted records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance

I have the following (My)SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE nidx = x ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

With the following assumptions:

- `id` is an indexed field
- `nidx` is a non-indexed field (let's say it has a numerical type)
- `x` is a constant
- record with `nidx = x` is relatively close in the ordered sequence of records (let's say it is guaranted to be somewhere among the first 1000 records in the order)

I have two questions:

1. Can I assume that this is an efficient query or should I add an index to `nidx` column?
2. Does the answer to the first question depends on the specific RDBMS (so it may by different for MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL, SQLite, etc.)? If yes, how it is for MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordering is applied after filtering.  The `ORDER BY` clause does not help the seach in this case.  Equally, unless you have some clear constraint on the table that indicates the values will be close, the optimiser doesn't know that and it won't help.

What -might- help, if you can't / won't apply an index on `nidx` is to first get the records around `id = x` and then search those.

Something like...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  id BETWEEN x - 1000 AND x + 1000
  AND nidx = x
ORDER BY
  id
LIMIT
  1
```

-Hopefully- this will allow the optimiser to build a plan where the 2000 records around `id=x` are found first, then only those 2000 records manually searched for `nidx= x`.

You'll have to try it and see, and use `EXPLAIN` to find out exactly what's being done in what order.

In general, however, this is a hack, don't rely on it too much.  Better to fix the indexing.

- Which is advice for all platforms

***Just add the index.*** :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the number of records, index would be preferrable.
Example in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE  table ADD INDEX nidx_index (nidx)
```

You can also create unique index for unique values:

```
ALTER TABLE  table ADD UNIQUE INDEX nidx_index (nidx)
```

Comment: The OP isn't asking *how* to add an index, they're asking if they really *need* to add the index, or can they rely on other features and behaviours instead.  Your answer should explain *why* they need the index, and that their described features won't change that.

Comment: Exactly as MatBailie said. I believe the crucial assumption is about the record being close in the order.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an index for the nidx field, but you have to keep in mind that this will make the UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE queries more inefficient.

The most penalizing of the sql queries with ORDER BY and GROUP BY, because they are operations that are performed at the end. If it is not necessary, I would remove the ORDER BY

finally you can use the EXPLAIN command to diagnose SQL queries

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE nidx = x ORDER BY id DESC
```

Here a little tutorial for improve a query using Explain
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-tutorial-visual-explain-dbt3.html

Comment: You've assumed `nidx` is unique.  It is possible that `ndix = x` yields multiple rows, then `ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` picks the one with the lowest `id`.  Your assumption *may* be valid, but it should at least be stated or questioned.